# Manage items in a List with their ids

Tags: list, flutter, dart

Let me explain, I have two List Views with `Items`. At the moment I don’t give an id to these items but I have a problem. In fact, when I remove an item from my favorites list, it doesn’t change the icon (favorite or not favorite) for the right item on the home_screen.

I want to get the place of the item in the menu screen so I can change the icon from the favorites list. I’m using the [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).
And so I wonder if it wouldn’t be better to create an `id` for each item and store a `List<int>` and then create a `List<Item>` in my favorites list. Also, I can use this id to change the right icon.

But I don’t know how to use these ids to create a List and then change the right icon.

Illustrations of what I said : [image: screenshot 1] [image: screenshot 2]

**Black** heart = in favorite  and  **White** heart = not in favorite.
It is the wrong item which is deleting.

[My code](https://github.com/Rianou20/my_app_from_scratch/tree/master/my_app_from_scratch) on Github ans some relevant parts of my code :

**favModel.dart**

```
class FavModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Item> favList = [];
  List<bool> isInFav = [];
  

  addInFavorite(title, description, index){
    Item item = Item(title: title, description: description, );
    favList.add(item);
    isInFav[index] = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  removeOfFavorite(int index, int index2){
    favList.removeAt(index);
    isInFav[index2] = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  implement(){
    isInFav.add(false);
  }
}
```

**favorite_screen.dart**

```
class Favorite extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Favorite'),
      ),
      body: Consumer<FavModel>(
        builder: (context, favModel, child) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: favModel.favList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return TextObject(favModel.favList[index].title,
                                    favModel.favList[index].description),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                      child: Icon(
                                        Icons.favorite,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                        size: 32,
                                      ),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        favModel.removeOfFavorite(index, index);
                                      }),
                                ),
           });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**home_screen.dart**

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                fullscreenDialog: true,
                builder: (context) {
                  return Favorite();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Consumer<FavModel>(builder: (context, favModel, child) {
        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: false,
            itemCount: itemData.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              favModel.implement();
              return TextObject(
                 itemData[index].title, itemData[index].description),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                              child: Icon(
                                favModel.isInFav.elementAt(index)
                                    ? Icons.favorite
                                    : Icons.favorite_border,
                                color:
                                    favModel.isInFav[index] ? Colors.red : null,
                                size: 32,
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                favModel.isInFav[index]
                                    ? null
                                    : Provider.of<FavModel>(context,
                                            listen: false)
                                        .addInFavorite(
                                        itemData[index].title,
                                        itemData[index].description,
                                        index,
                                      );
                              }),
              );
            });
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Where I want to get the index is in the favorite_screen.dart at this line `favModel.removeOfFavorite(index, index);`

Comment: I want two lists on two different screens. In the first screen you can add items and in the second you can remove them. I can do that, but I want to manage to change the right icon to the right item in the first screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to add `bool isFavorite` to your `class Item` and add an id for the class also. So you can avoid having two arrays.
And using the `id` will help you using some awesome methods like `findWhere` and `removeWhere`

**EDIT**
You can iterate the List using `for`

```
for(int i = 0;i<favList.length;i++){
   if(favList[i].id == selectedItem.id){
      favList[i].isSelected = true;
      break;// break the loop no need to continue
    }
}
notifyListeners()
```

Notice that now you have to pass `Item` instead of `index`

Comment: How I can change this bool for the right item with my provider ?

Comment: You can Iterate the List using ```For```, and check for ids inside

Comment: Use it where you have to update you list of favorite, in your case ```FavModel```

Comment: Hello, I have a new question in connection with this one. How do I make the favList a List<int> and not a List<Item>? The favList would be the list of ids that have been added to the favorites. But how do I create items corresponding to the right ids?

Comment: You mean going from list of ids to list of items ?

Comment: Yes, or maybe build those Items just with that list of ids and not create a second list of items

Comment: But why is that, it is totally fine to store the objects (It is the main concept of having classes), do you have something specific why you don't need to store the objects but only the ids ?

Comment: I thought it was better to just store the ids as favorites in a database

Comment: You can add field ```is_favorite``` to you database, it will be easier that way